# Can I read timed metadata/cue points from a live stream with JW Player in Flash mode?

Tags: jwplayer, live-streaming, database-metadata

I do this (read timed metadata) successfully in HTML5 mode on IOS devices with JW Player no problem.  But PC's running Flash have me scratching my head a bit.  Some background...

I create live synchronized presentations on the web. So a slide deck sits next to a video player on the screen. When a presenter in the video player says "go to slide 2" the slides switch to slide 2.

This happens because I have another app, a Flash based PowerPoint for lack of a better way to put it. This Flash based PowerPoint app is capable of making an RTMP connection to an RTMP streaming server, like Wowza or AMS, and asking it to find a video stream being published currently and inject metadata into it, like "slide 2" for example, with each slide advance. When this data is injected into the video stream, the stream transports the data to the video player at the viewing end where the data is extracted and acted upon by me, the player developer. I hear the text data message and tell the slide player in the page to advance.

As I mentioned, I am doing this just fine with JW player in HTML5 (IOS) mode. All working well. So if you are viewing on an iPad all is good.  But I'm not sure how to extract this data in JW player when it is in Flash mode on a PC. I don't see anything exposed in the API that might, say, let me hang an event listener for "onTextData" or "onCuePoint" type transmissions. Any other methods to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JW Player 7 has .on('meta'), which can be used for this purpose in Flash. In JW Player 7.3 (not out yet) it will also give you metadata on iOS.

https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference#metadata

Comment: Hmmm...  Tried that and on meta wasn't getting tripped client side.  Think I have to do the injection (send) right on the server though to make the connection.  Guess the handler name in the server side send should be "meta"?  Think I have it currently set to "onTextData" or something.  Let me adjust handler name and report back.